# Do I need a transit visa for a 23 hour layover in Amsterdam?

Tags: schengen, transit, transit-visas, south-african-citizens, ams

Does a South African citizen travelling from Canada to South Africa via Amsterdam, with a lay over of 23:50 need a transit visa?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Which visa do I need to travel to the Netherlands?](https://www.government.nl/topics/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/question-and-answer/which-visa-do-i-need-to-travel-to-the-netherlands), citizens of South Africa do not require a transit visa to change planes in Amsterdam.

However, you would need a regular Schengen visa if you would like to leave the airport. 23 hours is quite a long time to stay within the airport. It's certainly possible, but not very interesting.

Comment: Pieter should consider booking a room [here](http://www.mercure.com/gb/hotel-1730-mercure-hotel-schiphol-terminal/index.shtml)